# Google App Engine instances not starting

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a GAE application. Usually when I deploy a version of the app, almost automatically, an instance is created for it. But other times GAE doesn't start new instances. I could wait for 24h but nothing happens. I have to deploy several times the same version until finally GAE creates an instance for it. It's frankly annoying.

This situation didn't happen before, only for the last week or so.

I can't see anything in the logs. And the Instances administration panel just says "This app has no instances deployed".

Could it be that there is something wrong in my application? Or is it a GAE issue?

Comment: Sounds like an issue if it's intermittent.  Does the [old console](http://appengine.google.com) say the same thing?  What runtime are you using and what tool are you deploying with (e.g. `appcfg` or `gcloud`)?  Does the deployment give any errors?

Comment: The app engine version is 1.9.18 for python27 runtime. i deploy with appcfg.py and the deployment says that is successful. The old console doesn't show any instance and the Admin Logs is not showing errors. I've deployed several times just now and some of them worked fine, almost instantly. Others took around 5 minutes to start instances. This morning some of them didn't create an instance at all.

Comment: It seemed to be an issue on gae causing this kind of issue, are you still facing this issue ?

Comment: It hasn't happened since I posted this question... maybe it's fixed.

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. I deployed a testing version with `no-promote` so it doesn't receive traffic. I get a 'server not found' error in the browser when I try and connect to it using the link in the versions list and the instance count for the version remains at 0.