# Google App Engine version instances are not starting

Tags: google-app-engine

I have GAE application with 3 versions. Only default version has active instance, other two versions do not have active instances. Usually after deploy of any version, instance is created. But now that is not the case. Instances of non default versions wont to start after deploy, and I need those versions up.

I saw this question:
[Google App Engine instances not starting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125401/google-app-engine-instances-not-starting)

but there is no concrete answer.

Any idea how to start version instance?

Comment: Click on the link in the version list?

Comment: Configure your default module with min_idle_instances set to 1 (the default is 0). You'll have to re-deploy each version whose yaml config you change, of course. Be sure to handle startup requests correctly to enable the setting to work properly.

Comment: "Instances of non default versions wont to start after deploy" Do any errors show up in the logs?

Comment: I seem to have the same issue. I deployed a testing version with `no-promote` so it doesn't receive traffic. I get a 'server not found' error in the browser when I try and connect to it using the link in the versions list and the instance count for the version remains at 0.

Answer (score 0):

The version will start after you send it the first request (unless you use Managed VM - https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/managed-vms).

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you are trying to accomplish by having multiple versions running at the same time, having a little more info would really help providing a specific solution.

As @Vlad stated App Engine won't start (or keep) any app until it gets some traffic. you can start them by hitting ..appspot.com

If this "versions" are actually doing different things you should be implementing them as [Modules](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/)  .This way you can set up different rules for each module and setup the interactions between them.